# Hide links in quicklaunch for special groups

Tags: quick-launch

How can I hide links in quicklaunch for special usergroups?
For example only administrators should see administration-links.
I don't even know, if something like this is possible in a simple way or if I'll have to code a webpart for this.

Thanks in advance

Stefan Hennicken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a link to library or list you can set permissons for it so only people that have those permission can see it - [handling permissions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx#BM10) or look at target audience - [handling target audience](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx). Hope it will help.

Comment: It helped me to understand, what I could do to hide lists somebody shouldn't see. Thanks a lot for that.
But in my quicklauch, there are also different views of the same list and by showing only the links a specific group will work with, we try to make it easier to work in the sharepoint enviroment. As far as I know now, it isn't possible to achieve this (hiding some links a specific user/group will not have to work with) by handling permissions and/or target audience, because these permission focus on complete lists.

Comment: So you just need to see records for specific group?

Comment: Exactly. 3 groups should see different links to different views based on the same list in their quicklaunch.

Comment: How about create attitional column where to store what kind of group can see this item and filter by it on view - in that case you can have one link for 3 groups

Comment: Good idea, but the different views also provide different kind of sortings for each view.

Comment: Hm, the only option for me would be to do some coding), maybe the simplest way is to leave all links in quick launch and filter on all views + additional sorting. It's really makes me curios how to solve this problem.

Comment: I thought a few days about it and still can't find a way to win the battle against sharepoint. Coding would be ok, but I'm not sure where to start. At the moment all links are in my quicklaunch and I'm going to hide the links that aren't needed. I think that's what you meant, too. Will I have to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean completely remove links? - then you shold go to **Site Settings -> Quick Launch** and remove links that you dont need in your quicklaunch. And when i meant "coding" i thought about creating some Web Part and playing in VS with SPNavigation class (with it QuickLaunch property). I don't know if it is posible to determine if user belongs to some by JavaScript, but if so - why not?

Comment: I didn't try it in Visual Studio and never worked with SPNavigation-Class ....till now. I'll check tomorow, if I can get the results I'm looking for without having lots of knowledge. Thanks again for your replies Andriy!

Answer (score 0):

maybe following code snippet will help you

```
         public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (var oWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
            {

                SPNavigationNode node = oWeb.Navigation.AddToQuickLaunch(new SPNavigationNode("link", "Lists/yourList/view1.aspx", false), SPQuickLaunchHeading.Lists);
                node.Properties["Audience"] = ";;;;yourGroup";
                node.Update();
             }
        }
```